# Area Integration in complex plane using python dblquad

Tags: python, numerical-integration, plane

my problem is related to Quantum Optics. I am trying to determine the Wigner Function for a Fock state, which involves integration in the complex plane. My code is very slow though, so I would like to ask if you could help me to improve the speed?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import pylab
import numpy as np
import mpmath
import sys
mpmath.dps = 5
from sympy import laguerre_l
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import quad,dblquad

def complex_quadrature(func, a, b, **kwargs):
    def real_func(x,y):
    return scipy.real(func(complex(x,y)))
def imag_func(x,y):
    return scipy.imag(func(complex(x,y)))
real_integral = dblquad(real_func, a, b, lambda x: a, lambda x: b, **kwargs)
imag_integral = dblquad(imag_func, a, b, lambda x: a, lambda x: b, **kwargs)
return complex(real_integral[0], imag_integral[0])

f = lambda z: 1/(np.pi**2)*complex_quadrature(lambda x:scipy.exp(x.conjugate()*z-        x*z.conjugate())*complex(laguerre_l(1,0,abs(x)**2),0)*scipy.exp(-abs(x)**2), -5, 5)

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
X = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.1)
Y = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
xn, yn = X.shape
W = X*0

for xk in range(xn):
for yk in range(yn):
    try:
        z = complex(X[xk,yk],Y[xk,yk])
        print (f(z))
        w = abs(z)
                if w != w:
            raise ValueError
            W[xk,yk] = w
        except (ValueError, TypeError, ZeroDivisionError):
                pass

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, W, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet,linewidth=0,alpha=.9)
pylab.show()
```

Note: Most of this was copied and modified from stackoverflow, so I don't claim ownership...

Comment: I guess it will be a lot easier or at least faster to map the complex plane to a two dimensional real space.

Comment: `if w != w`? seriously? Also the code pasted needs better indentation

Answer (score 1):

```
z = complex(X[xk,yk],Y[xk,yk])
##  print (f(z))    ## <---- Commenting this line will solve your problem
w = abs(z)
```